# Laravel + Vuejs, Style missing when reloading children router path

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

When I navigating using the links(href) the http://localhost:8080/user/profile page works, but then if I refresh the page (Ctrl + F5), it shows the content but the style is missing. Any idea?

## routes.js

```
{
    path: '/user',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: require('./components/pages/Dashboard'),
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: false
    },
    props: { bcName: "Dashboard" },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'profile',
            name: 'Profile',
            components: {
                mainarea: require('./components/pages/Profile'),
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

## Usermain.vue

```
<template>
<!-- Content Column -->
<div class="col-lg-9 mb-4">
<router-view name="mainarea"> </router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

## Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
    <!-- Content Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <user-sidebar></user-sidebar>
        <user-main></user-main>
    </div>
</template>
```

## Profile.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="test">Profile page {{layout}}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: please make any live demo of this ?

Comment: This is the working page :  https://ibb.co/gqJhZo     and this is the page having issue: https://ibb.co/nFepEo

Comment: so that we can reproduce the error

Comment: https://175458bd.ngrok.io      Please click on dashboard and then profile. you can see the working page, and now press Ctrl + F5 and see the style missing

Comment: Yes I can see, may be you have included css in your landing page url. did you try with `hash` mode?

Comment: like you will get url as `http://localhost:8080/#/user/profile`

Comment: I included the css in resources/view/welcome.blade.php and the location of the css file is public/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css  . Any mistakes in that? or  how to use hash mode?

Comment: where you used `router` ?

Comment: Yes, its working with hash mode.. but is there any way to remove hash ?

Comment: router is in resources/asset/js